# Opening the modal dialog using js

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

I have following Modal Dialog (popup) using **only CSS3** in my asp page for user registration:
**HTML :**

```
<%-- Modal PopUp starts here--%>
    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close" onclick="DisableAllPopUpTxt()">X</a>

            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMSG2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="Email ID Already Taken " Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                        <input id="txtCustFName" name="txtCustFName" type="text" required placeholder="Enter Your First Name" style="width: 80%" />
                    </td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                        <input id="txtCustLName" name="txtCustLName" type="text" required placeholder="Enter Your Last Name" style="width: 80%" />
                    </td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                        <input id="txtCustREmail" name="txtCustREmail" type="email" required placeholder="Enter Valid Email ID" style="width: 80%" />
                    </td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                        <input id="txtCustRPwd" name="txtCustRPwd" type="password" required placeholder="Enter Password" style="width: 80%" />
                    </td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                        <input id="txtCustRePwd" name="txtCustRePwd" type="password" required placeholder="ReType Password" style="width: 80%" />
                    </td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                        <input id="txtCustPh" name="txtCustPh" type="number" size="10" min="10" max="10" required placeholder="Enter Valid Mobile No" style="width: 80%" />
                    </td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style1" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;" onclick="btnSignUp()">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSingUp" runat="server" onclick="signUp" Text="Login" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%--Modal PopUp Ends Here--%>
```

**CSS :**

```
.modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
        }

    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
        }

    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 400px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        }

    .close {
        background: #606061;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        line-height: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -12px;
        text-align: center;
        top: -10px;
        width: 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;}
    .close:hover { background: #00d9ff; 
                   }
```

In my asp page I've following anchor tag which is used to display the popup:

```
<a href="#openModal" id="DialogLink" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold">Register</a>
```

**Now the problem is:**

As this is registration form, I want server side validation of existing email id .
If user entered email id already exist in DB I want to reopen the above modal dialog with an error message Email ID already exist.

I'm not able to reopen that dialog box.
Is there any way to do this using js?

The tutorial for modal dialog is on site:
[click here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/)

For visualizing modal dialog:
[click here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/95565062@N06/8715526791/)

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I think, you should not close it anyway and use ajax for the validation and the message. Are you with me on this?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using ajax....Please check the below sample code

```
$("#btnSubmit").live("click",(function(e) {
        var emailAddress = $.trim($('#txtEmailAddress').val());
        try
        { 
          var reqUrl = "http://mysite/Sample/Sample.aspx?post=true";
          var jqXHRresponse;
          var request = $.ajax({
                      url: reqUrl,
                      type: "POST",
                      data: {email:emailAddress},
                      dataType: 'json',
                      success:function (data, status, jqXHR) { 
                              jqXHRresponse = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText); 
                              if(jqXHRresponse.result == 'success')
                              {
                                /Do Something/
                              }
                              else if(jqXHRresponse.result == 'emailexist')
                              {
                                 DisplayErrorMessages('Email Already Exist');
                              }
                      });
  return false; }));
```

### C#

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
  if (Request.Params["post"] == "true")
  {
    submitValues(Request.Params["email"]);
  }
}

public void submitValues(string email)
{
 string returnValue = string.Empty;
 //Call DB and send response back

 Response.Write("{\"result\":\"" + retrunValue+ "\"}");
 Response.End();
}
```